# Flex audio input peak meter?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I'm looking for a simple way to do a peak meter for a Flex application I have that needs microphone input. Is there some component designed for this ? I have googled a lot, and haven't found a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this in Flex 3.4, but this might be limited to Adobe AIR.
flash.media.Microphone

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/media/Microphone.html

Also, this .NET tutorial might give you some cool ideas:
blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx